# Баг в html письме линия

Tags: html, css, email

появляются линии между блоками, если открывать письмо через мобильную веб версию yandex.ru, mail.ru и тд.,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**вот код письма**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"> 
 <head> 
  <title>
      &#x41f;&#x438;&#x441;&#x44c;&#x43c;&#x43e;
    </title> <!--[if !mso]><!--> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!--<![endif]--> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <style type="text/css">
      #outlook a { padding:0; }
      body { margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; }
      table, td { border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
      img { border:0;height:auto;line-height:100%; outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
      p { display:block;margin:13px 0; }
    </style> <!--[if mso]>
    <noscript>
    <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      <o:AllowPNG/>
      <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    </noscript>
    <![endif]--> <!--[if lte mso 11]>
    <style type="text/css">
      .mj-outlook-group-fix { width:100% !important; }
    </style>
    <![endif]--> <!--[if !mso]><!--> 
  <link href="'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;1,700&amp;display=swap'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
  <style type="text/css">
          @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;1,700&display=swap');
        </style> <!--<![endif]--> 
  <style type="text/css">
      @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
        .mj-column-per-100 { width:100% !important; max-width: 100%; }
.mj-column-per-40 { width:40% !important; max-width: 40%; }
.mj-column-per-60 { width:60% !important; max-width: 60%; }
.mj-column-per-30 { width:30% !important; max-width: 30%; }
.mj-column-per-70 { width:70% !important; max-width: 70%; }
.mj-column-per-50 { width:50% !important; max-width: 50%; }
.mj-column-per-7-6923076923076925 { width:7.6923076923076925% !important; max-width: 7.6923076923076925%; }
      }
    </style> 
  <style media="screen and (min-width:480px)">
      .moz-text-html .mj-column-per-100 { width:100% !important; max-width: 100%; }
.moz-text-html .mj-column-per-40 { width:40% !important; max-width: 40%; }
.moz-text-html .mj-column-per-60 { width:60% !important; max-width: 60%; }
.moz-text-html .mj-column-per-30 { width:30% !important; max-width: 30%; }
.moz-text-html .mj-column-per-70 { width:70% !important; max-width: 70%; }
.moz-text-html .mj-column-per-50 { width:50% !important; max-width: 50%; }
.moz-text-html .mj-column-per-7-6923076923076925 { width:7.6923076923076925% !important; max-width: 7.6923076923076925%; }
    </style> 
  <style type="text/css">
    
    

    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
      table.mj-full-width-mobile { width: 100% !important; }
      td.mj-full-width-mobile { width: auto !important; }
    }
  
    </style> 
  <style type="text/css">
    a { text-decoration: none!important; color: inherit!important;}
      .body {
        font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif !important;
      }
      p {
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 490px) {
        .end {
          font-size: 20px;
        }
        .mnone {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .pad0 {
          padding: 0 !important;
        }
        .mobileimg img {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center !important;
        }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
        .emailmobile div p{
          text-align: center !important;
          margin-bottom: 20px !important;
        }
        .section-mobile-footer .padding16 {
            padding-left: 16px !important;
            padding-right: 16px !important;
        }
        .btnk table {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .mobile_center {
          text-align: center !important;
        }
        .mpad {
          padding-left: 16px !important;
          padding-right: 16px !important;
        }
        .padding-m {
          margin-bottom: 24px;
        }
      }
    </style> 
 </head> 
 <body style="word-spacing:normal;"> 
  <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;">
    &#x41f;&#x43e;&#x437;&#x434;&#x440;&#x430;&#x432;&#x43b;&#x44f;&#x435;&#x43c; &#x441; &#x440;&#x435;&#x433;&#x438;&#x441;&#x442;&#x440;&#x430;&#x446;&#x438;&#x435;&#x439; &#x43d;&#x430; &#x441;&#x430;&#x439;&#x442;&#x435; https://formula.ekfgroup.com !
  </div> 
  <div class="body" style=""> <!--[if mso | IE]><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="section-mobile-outlook" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600" bgcolor="#1E1E1C" ><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><![endif]--> 
   <div class="section-mobile" style="background:#1E1E1C;background-color:#1E1E1C;margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"> 
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#1E1E1C;background-color:#1E1E1C;width:100%;"> 
     <tbody> 
      <tr> 
       <td class="mpad" style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:16px 32px 16px 32px;text-align:center;"> <!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="" style="width:536px;" ><![endif]--> 
        <div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0;line-height:0;text-align:left;display:inline-block;width:100%;direction:ltr;"> <!--[if mso | IE]><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" ><tr><td style="vertical-align:middle;width:214px;" ><![endif]--> 
         <div class="mj-column-per-40 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:40%;"> 
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
           <tbody> 
            <tr> 
             <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding:0px;"> 
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
               <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                 <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                   <tbody> 
                    <tr> 
                     <td style="width:107px;"> <a href="https://formula.ekfgroup.com/" target="_blank"> <img height="auto" src="https://ekfline.ekfgroup.com/mail/logo.png" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;font-size:13px;" width="107"> </a> </td> 
                    </tr> 
                   </tbody> 
                  </table> </td> 
                </tr> 
               </tbody> 
              </table> </td> 
            </tr> 
           </tbody> 
          </table> 
         </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td><td style="vertical-align:middle;width:321px;" ><![endif]--> 
         <div class="mj-column-per-60 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:60%;"> 
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
           <tbody> 
            <tr> 
             <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding:0px;"> 
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
               <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                 <td align="right" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-top:0px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                   <tbody> 
                    <tr> 
                     <td style="width:107px;"> <a href="https://formula.ekfgroup.com/" target="_blank"> <img height="19" src="https://ekfline.ekfgroup.com/mail/logo2.png" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:19px;width:100%;font-size:13px;" width="107"> </a> </td> 
                    </tr> 
                   </tbody> 
                  </table> </td> 
                </tr> 
               </tbody> 
              </table> </td> 
            </tr> 
           </tbody> 
          </table> 
         </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> 
        </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td> 
      </tr> 
     </tbody> 
    </table> 
   </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600" bgcolor="#1E1E1C" ><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><v:rect style="width:600px;" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"><v:fill origin="0.5, 0" position="0.5, 0" src="https://ekfline.ekfgroup.com/mail/go.png" color="#1E1E1C" type="tile" /><v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0"><![endif]--> 
   <div style="background:#1E1E1C url('https://ekfline.ekfgroup.com/mail/go.png') center top / auto no-repeat;background-position:center top;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto;margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"> 
    <div style="line-height:0;font-size:0;"> 
     <table align="center" background="https://ekfline.ekfgroup.com/mail/go.png" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#1E1E1C url('https://ekfline.ekfgroup.com/mail/go.png') center top / auto no-repeat;background-position:center top;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto;width:100%;"> 
      <tbody> 
       <tr> 
        <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:50px;text-align:center;"> <!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;" ><![endif]--> 
         <div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"> 
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
           <tbody> 
            <tr> 
             <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:40px;"> 
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
               <tbody> 
               </tbody> 
              </table> </td> 
            </tr> 
           </tbody> 
          </table> 
         </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td> 
       </tr> 
      </tbody> 
     </table> 
    </div> 
   </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></v:textbox></v:rect></td></tr></table><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="section-mobile-outlook" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600" bgcolor="#1E1E1C" ><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><![endif]--> 
   <div class="section-mobile" style="background:#1E1E1C;background-color:#1E1E1C;margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"> 
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#1E1E1C;background-color:#1E1E1C;width:100%;"> 
     <tbody> 
      <tr> 
       <td class="mpad" style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px 32px 20px 32px;text-align:center;"> <!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:536px;" ><![endif]--> 
        <div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"> 
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
          <tbody> 
           <tr> 
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;"> 
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
              <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:6px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <div style="font-family:Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:22px;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;line-height:1.3;text-align:left;color:#ffffff;">
                  &#x417;&#x434;&#x440;&#x430;&#x432;&#x441;&#x442;&#x432;&#x443;&#x439;&#x442;&#x435;, #NAME#!
                 </div> </td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <div style="font-family:Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;text-align:left;color:#ffffff;">
                  &#x41f;&#x43e;&#x437;&#x434;&#x440;&#x430;&#x432;&#x43b;&#x44f;&#x435;&#x43c;! &#x420;&#x435;&#x433;&#x438;&#x441;&#x442;&#x440;&#x430;&#x446;&#x438;&#x44f; &#x43f;&#x440;&#x43e;&#x448;&#x43b;&#x430; &#x443;&#x441;&#x43f;&#x435;&#x448;&#x43d;&#x43e;. 
                  <br class="mnone"> &#x414;&#x435;&#x43b;&#x43e; &#x437;&#x430; &#x43c;&#x430;&#x43b;&#x44b;&#x43c; &#x2014; &#x434;&#x43e;&#x439;&#x442;&#x438; &#x434;&#x43e; &#x444;&#x438;&#x43d;&#x430;&#x43b;&#x430; &#x438; &#x43d;&#x430;&#x431;&#x440;&#x430;&#x442;&#x44c; &#x43c;&#x430;&#x43a;&#x441;&#x438;&#x43c;&#x430;&#x43b;&#x44c;&#x43d;&#x43e;&#x435; &#x43a;&#x43e;&#x43b;&#x438;&#x447;&#x435;&#x441;&#x442;&#x432;&#x43e; &#x431;&#x430;&#x43b;&#x43b;&#x43e;&#x432;.
                 </div> </td> 
               </tr> <!-- <mj-button css-class="btnk" font-family="Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif" --><!-- background-color="#f45e43" --><!-- border-radius="0" --><!-- font-size="14px" --><!-- height="50px" --><!-- padding="0" --><!-- color="#ffffff !important" --><!-- href="#" --><!-- width="54%" --><!-- font-weight="500" --><!-- > --><!-- Узнать результат --><!-- </mj-button> --> 
              </tbody> 
             </table> </td> 
           </tr> 
          </tbody> 
         </table> 
        </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td> 
      </tr> 
     </tbody> 
    </table> 
   </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" ><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><![endif]--> 
   <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"> 
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;"> 
     <tbody> 
      <tr> 
       <td class="mpad" style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:40px;padding-left:32px;padding-right:32px;padding-top:40px;text-align:center;"> <!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:160.8px;" ><![endif]--> 
        <div class="mj-column-per-30 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"> 
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
          <tbody> 
           <tr> 
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;"> 
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
              <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="center" class="mobileimg" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                  <tbody> 
                   <tr> 
                    <td style="width:160px;"> <img height="auto" src="https://ekfline.ekfgroup.com/mail/first.png" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;font-size:13px;" width="160"> </td> 
                   </tr> 
                  </tbody> 
                 </table> </td> 
               </tr> 
              </tbody> 
             </table> </td> 
           </tr> 
          </tbody> 
         </table> 
        </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td><td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:375.2px;" ><![endif]--> 
        <div class="mj-column-per-70 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"> 
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
          <tbody> 
           <tr> 
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;padding-top:24px;"> 
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
              <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="left" class="pad0" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:6px;padding-left:32px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <div style="font-family:Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:22px;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;line-height:1.3;text-align:left;color:#1E1E1C;">
                  &#x41a;&#x430;&#x43a; &#x44d;&#x442;&#x43e; &#x441;&#x434;&#x435;&#x43b;&#x430;&#x442;&#x44c;?
                 </div> </td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="left" class="pad0" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:6px;padding-left:32px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <div style="font-family:Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;text-align:left;color:#1E1E1C;">
                  &#x412;&#x44b;&#x43f;&#x43e;&#x43b;&#x43d;&#x44f;&#x439;&#x442;&#x435; &#x437;&#x430;&#x434;&#x430;&#x43d;&#x438;&#x44f; &#x43d;&#x430; &#x441;&#x430;&#x439;&#x442;&#x435;, &#x43f;&#x43e;&#x43b;&#x443;&#x447;&#x430;&#x439;&#x442;&#x435; &#x431;&#x430;&#x43b;&#x43b;&#x44b; &#x438; &#x43f;&#x43e;&#x434;&#x43d;&#x438;&#x43c;&#x430;&#x439;&#x442;&#x435;&#x441;&#x44c; &#x43d;&#x430; &#x432;&#x435;&#x440;&#x448;&#x438;&#x43d;&#x443; &#x442;&#x443;&#x440;&#x43d;&#x438;&#x440;&#x43d;&#x43e;&#x439; &#x442;&#x430;&#x431;&#x43b;&#x438;&#x446;&#x44b;.
                 </div> </td> 
               </tr> 
              </tbody> 
             </table> </td> 
           </tr> 
          </tbody> 
         </table> 
        </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td> 
      </tr> 
     </tbody> 
    </table> 
   </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" ><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><![endif]--> 
   <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"> 
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;"> 
     <tbody> 
      <tr> 
       <td class="mpad" style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:40px;padding-left:32px;padding-right:32px;text-align:center;"> <!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:160.8px;" ><![endif]--> 
        <div class="mj-column-per-30 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"> 
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
          <tbody> 
           <tr> 
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;"> 
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
              <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="center" class="mobileimg" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                  <tbody> 
                   <tr> 
                    <td style="width:160px;"> <img height="auto" src="https://ekfline.ekfgroup.com/mail/two.png" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;font-size:13px;" width="160"> </td> 
                   </tr> 
                  </tbody> 
                 </table> </td> 
               </tr> 
              </tbody> 
             </table> </td> 
           </tr> 
          </tbody> 
         </table> 
        </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td><td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:375.2px;" ><![endif]--> 
        <div class="mj-column-per-70 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"> 
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
          <tbody> 
           <tr> 
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;padding-top:15px;"> 
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
              <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="left" class="pad0" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:6px;padding-left:32px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <div style="font-family:Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:22px;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;line-height:1.3;text-align:left;color:#1E1E1C;">
                  &#x41a;&#x430;&#x43a; &#x43f;&#x43e;&#x43b;&#x443;&#x447;&#x438;&#x442;&#x44c; &#x431;&#x43e;&#x43b;&#x44c;&#x448;&#x435; &#x431;&#x430;&#x43b;&#x43b;&#x43e;&#x432;?
                 </div> </td> 
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="left" class="pad0" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:6px;padding-left:32px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <div style="font-family:Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;text-align:left;color:#1E1E1C;">
                  &#x41e;&#x431;&#x440;&#x430;&#x449;&#x430;&#x439;&#x442;&#x435; &#x432;&#x43d;&#x438;&#x43c;&#x430;&#x43d;&#x438;&#x435; &#x43d;&#x430; &#x434;&#x43e;&#x43f;&#x43e;&#x43b;&#x43d;&#x438;&#x442;&#x435;&#x43b;&#x44c;&#x43d;&#x44b;&#x435; &#x443;&#x441;&#x43b;&#x43e;&#x432;&#x438;&#x44f;, &#x437;&#x430; &#x43a;&#x43e;&#x442;&#x43e;&#x440;&#x44b;&#x435; &#x442;&#x430;&#x43a;&#x436;&#x435; &#x43c;&#x43e;&#x436;&#x43d;&#x43e; &#x43f;&#x43e;&#x43b;&#x443;&#x447;&#x438;&#x442;&#x44c; &#x431;&#x430;&#x43b;&#x43b;&#x44b; &#x2014; &#x44d;&#x442;&#x43e; &#x434;&#x430;&#x441;&#x442; &#x432;&#x430;&#x43c; &#x43f;&#x440;&#x435;&#x438;&#x43c;&#x443;&#x449;&#x435;&#x441;&#x442;&#x432;&#x43e;.
                 </div> </td> 
               </tr> 
              </tbody> 
             </table> </td> 
           </tr> 
          </tbody> 
         </table> 
        </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td> 
      </tr> 
     </tbody> 
    </table> 
   </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="padding-m-outlook" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600" bgcolor="#1E1E1C" ><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><![endif]--> 
   <div class="padding-m" style="background:#1E1E1C;background-color:#1E1E1C;margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"> 
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#1E1E1C;background-color:#1E1E1C;width:100%;"> 
     <tbody> 
      <tr> 
       <td class="mpad" style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:32px;text-align:center;"> <!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:536px;" ><![endif]--> 
        <div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"> 
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
          <tbody> 
           <tr> 
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;"> 
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
              <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:6px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <div style="font-family:Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:22px;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;line-height:1.3;text-align:left;color:#ffffff;">
                  &#x41d;&#x435; &#x43f;&#x440;&#x43e;&#x43f;&#x443;&#x441;&#x43a;&#x430;&#x439; &#x43d;&#x430;&#x448;&#x438; &#x43f;&#x438;&#x441;&#x44c;&#x43c;&#x430;!
                 </div> </td> 
               </tr> 
              </tbody> 
             </table> </td> 
           </tr> 
          </tbody> 
         </table> 
        </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td> 
      </tr> 
     </tbody> 
    </table> 
   </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600" bgcolor="#1E1E1C" ><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><![endif]--> 
   <div style="background:#1E1E1C;background-color:#1E1E1C;margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"> 
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#1E1E1C;background-color:#1E1E1C;width:100%;"> 
     <tbody> 
      <tr> 
       <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-bottom:22px;padding-left:x;padding-right:10px;text-align:center;"> <!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:NaNpx;" ><![endif]--> 
        <div class="mj-column-per-50 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;"> 
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%"> 
          <tbody> 
           <tr> 
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;padding-top:15px;"> 
             <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%"> 
              <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;"> 
                 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                  <tbody> 
    
                 
    </table> 
   </div> <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> 
  </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

**прошу помочь с проблемой**

Comment: У меня к примеру [не появляется](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn0Zy.png). Нужно более подробная информация. Когда появляется, при каких обстоятельствах появляется?

Comment: Уххх, тут прям вагон ошибок, Вы би письма хоть валидатором проверяли. Или, лишь бы gmail открывался, а на другие менеджеры пофиг. )